# QCheckListItem doesn't exist

Tags: qt

Does anybody knows what happen with QCheckListItem in qt 4? I included this header but I'm getting an error telling that file doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your [friend](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/porting4.html).

> The `QListView`, `QListViewItem`, `QCheckListItem`, and
>   `QListViewItemIterator` classes have been renamed Q3ListView,
>   Q3ListViewItem, Q3CheckListItem, and Q3ListViewItemIterator, and have
>   been moved to the Qt3Support library. New Qt applications should use
>   one of the following four classes instead: `QTreeView` or `QTreeWidget`
>   for tree-like structures; `QListWidget` or the new `QListView` class for
>   one-dimensional lists.

There is no need to use `QCheckListItem` since it is a deprecated class.